# Selenium IDE- Clicking on a dynamic id

Tags: html, selenium-ide

I'm using the Selenium IDE and trying to get it to click on a specific search bar in a page, but the id of the search bar changes every time the page is refreshed.  There are no other unique things I can use for contains().

```
<div class="ace_content" id="id-46319949-a1be-4d53-a2a8-fa644b37485b" style="margin-top: 0px; width: 764px; height: 60px; margin-left: 0px;">
```

This is the HTML.  Is there any other way of finding the search bar?

Comment: HTML is still missing

Comment: Resolved.  I used this
    //*[@class='ace_content']
to identify this xpath because ace_content was unique.

Comment: This question is unlikely to help anyone else, since it's impossible to tell what's unique with the information given, not to mention the fact that you state that there are no other unique things you can use... Feel free to delete it.There are no other unique things I can use

Answer (score 0):

As per the [selenium docs](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html), you have various selectors to choose from, other than id. 
You can select on the class which appears to be static:

`driver.find_elements_by_class_name('ace_content')`

If multiple `ace_content` divs exist on the page, you can select the nth occurence of the div by just getting the n-1 index of the list returned by `find_elements_by_class_name`.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. I used this 
    //*[@class='ace_content']
to identify this xpath because ace_content was unique.